# How to setup my Angular directive in my case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive with isolate scope.

I have

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('itemCollection',  
['$cookies',     
    function($cookies) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                items: '='
            },
            link: function(scope) {
                    console.log(scope.items)
                    console.log(items)
                    --> both console.log show undefined
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Html

```
<item-collection items="item1"></item-collection>
```

I can't seem to get the `'item1'` in my directive and it's undefined. I am not sure what I am missing. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks!

Comment: Is `item1` set to anything in your parent scope?

Comment: what about turning item1 in your html into a string? <item-collection items="'item1'"></item-collection> item1 is an object in your case, if it's not defined, then that makes sense. so just try making it a string and please report back. that should solve it.

Comment: All we can say for sure is that it's `undefined` **at that moment**. If you want to know how to setup your directive then you should show us your directive or at least tell us something about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `item1` come asynchronusly? If it is, you need to set up a watch in your directive and process as soon as it is available.

```
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            items: '='
        },
        link: function(scope) {
                console.log(scope.items)
                console.log(items)
                --> both console.log show undefined

            scope.$watch(
                function() { return scope.items; },
                function(newValue) {
                    if (newValue != null) {
                        console.log('not null:' + newValue);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('still null, skip');
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    };
```